# How to execute the following commands in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am working in the following scripto to activate the front end and back end of my project as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/perf-fe/
source my_project_34/bin/activate
npm start 
&&
cd /Users/perf-be/
export FLASK_APP=router.py
flask run
```

However it is not working, It is showing just the first part:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/perf-fe/
source my_project_34/bin/activate
npm start 
&&
```

Since the first process occupies the entire terminal, I would like to appreciate suggestions

Comment: What do you think the line with `&&` will do and what do you want it to do?

Comment: @Jesse_b I am using that in order to continue with the following commands

Comment: It should be giving a syntax error.  That is not a valid use of `&&`

Comment: @neo33 you want to make the:
npm start run in background right?

Comment: @vfbsilva yes I want that, something to return the control of the terminal

Comment: Check the answer from @DopeGhoti :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to start the first process in its own job, and then execute the second:

```
cd /Users/perf-fe/
source my_project_34/bin/activate
npm start &
cd /Users/perf-be/
export FLASK_APP=router.py
flask run
```

The `&` tells the shell to run the previous command as a background job, and to continue with the next command even though the prior is still running.

This is distinct from `&&`, which is a syntax error as you present it.  Its use is *between* two commands, to execute the second if and only if the exit code of the first is zero.